# Synchronous Consumer with JMS Queue

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

I want to process all the messages from a JMS Queue in Glassfish 3 in a synchronous way so I have tried to change the property Maximum Active Consumers from -1 to 1 in JMS Physical Destination in Glassfish window. I think setting this I will have only one Consumer executing OnMessage() at the same time. The problem I have reached its that when I change that property I got this error:

```
[I500]: Caught JVM Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

[I500]: Caught JVM Exception: com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

sendMessage Error [C4038]: com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

If anyone know another way to make the method onmessage() synchronous will be appreciated. This is my Consumer Class:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "QueueListener", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class MessageBean implements MessageListener {



@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    write("MessageBean has received " + message);
    try{

        TextMessage result=(TextMessage)message;
        String text=result.getText();
        write("OTAMessageBean message ID has resolved to " + text);
        int messageID=Integer.valueOf(text);

        AirProcessing aP=new AirProcessing();
        aP.pickup(messageID);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        raiseError("OTAMessageBean error " + e.getMessage());
    }
   long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   write("MessageBean has finished in " + (t2-t1)); 

}



}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the only solution I found was to set up a `Schedule` which polls the messages from the queue every ten seconds:

```
@Stateless
public class MyReceiver {
   @Resource(mappedName = "jms/MyQueueFactory")
   private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
   @Resource(mappedName = "jms/MyQueue")
   private Queue myQueue;
   private QueueConnection qc;
   private QueueSession session;
   private MessageConsumer consumer;


   @PostConstruct
   void init() {
       try {
         qc = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
         session = qc.createQueueSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         consumer = session.createConsumer(myQueue);
         qc.start();
       } catch (JMSException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }

   @PreDestroy
   void cleanup() throws JMSException {
     qc.close();
   }

   @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/10", persistent = false)
   public void onMessage() throws JMSException {
     Message message;
     while ((message = consumer.receiveNoWait()) != null) {
       ObjectMessage objMsg = (ObjectMessage) message;
       Serializable content;
       try {
         content = objMsg.getObject();

         //Do sth. with "content" here

         message.acknowledge();
       } catch (JMSException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JMS is async by nature, you don't have a specific config for telling io to behave synchronously. You can simulate it by adding message delivery and consumption confirmations everywhere, but that's not really how JMS is intended to work. Try RMI[enter link description here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) or maybe HTTP (or something on top of it like a SOAP or REST web service)

Comment: I want to have an unique single threaded consumer. The problem I have is that onMessage() is executing async per message received, so if I have 10 producers sending one message each, I will have 10 consumers at the same time, so the queue is "always empty". The theoretical purpose of a Queue is holding messages (in a FIFO or LIFO way) until any consumer gets one and process it. If a queue creates unlimited threads of consumers what is the benefits of using queues?

Comment: Well, as you say, JMS is a Prodcer-Consumer paradigm implementation, and it's one that's made to run (produce/consume) in an asynch way, in the sense that neither the producer nor the consumer need to wait for one another to finish. There's benefits to that, like not blocking uselessly when the "consuming" part is only available later on from when the producer finishes. At any rate, JMS can be use synchronously or asynchronously but IMHO it's not really made for synch operation (at least for the reason of the overhead it implies as compared to other ways of achieving this)