# JMS Consumer to Synchronously receive Message from Remote Producer using Glassfish and OpenMQ

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, synchronous, openmq

I am using Glassfish and OpenMQ for a remote Consumer instance to look up a message Producer's queue and process requests synchronously.

According to McIntosh's answer on [Synchronous Consumer with JMS Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528818/synchronous-consumer-with-jms-queue),
synchronous message receiving can be handled via scheduling. I plan on doing this, but I have only seen examples of connecting to a message queue by way of an asynchronous Message Driven Bean (MDB), as shown below:

```
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "addressList", propertyValue = "mq://localhost:54020/"), //found in Producer server's domain.xml as JMS_PROVIDER_PORT
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/ProducerRequestMessageQueue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")})

public class ConsumerNode extends Node implements MessageListener  {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext _mdc;

    public ConsumerNode() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        //process message...
    }
}
```

How do I connect to the remote Producer queue without implementing `MessageListener` and setting up as a Message Driven Bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was needing the imq.jar mq library located at:

> %GLASSFISH_HOME%/mq/lib/

The following code answers my question with core pieces being the `init()` and `onMessage()` methods:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.StreamMessage;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Queue;

//from imq.jar
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration;
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory;

@Singleton
public class SyncNode {
    private ConnectionFactory _producerRequestFactory;
    private Connection _connection;
    private Session _session;
    private Queue _producerRequestMessageQueue;
    private MessageConsumer _consumer;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        try {
            _producerRequestFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            _producerRequestFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqBrokerHostName, "localhost");
            _producerRequestFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqBrokerHostPort, "56527"); //56527 is JMS_PROVIDER_PORT found in producer's domain.xml in domain config directory
            _connection = _producerRequestFactory.createConnection();
            _session = _connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            _producerRequestMessageQueue = _session.createQueue("ProducerRequestMessageQueue"); //name of the queue that the producer sends messages to.
            _consumer = _session.createConsumer(_producerRequestMessageQueue);
            _connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void cleanup() {
        try {
            _consumer.close();
            _session.close();
            _connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/10", persistent = false)
    public void onMessage() {
        try {
            _connection.start(); 
            Message message = _consumer.receive();
            //handle message
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
           //handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Two code examples helped me:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531060/5166179) taught me the proper annotations to escape using the main method.
2. [This tutorial](http://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/snippets/java/hello-world-java-message-service-with-open-mq#TOC-Example-Code) helped make things click on how to connect to another server, or port in my case.